# Relationship between the Res folder and the R.java file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 3 separate namespaces in my project, id like them to have separate resource folders, but my problem is, they dont make a  app/build/generated/R.java file.  So questions are the following.

How would i go about adding separate res folders without merging my files.
How would i generate that Res in a R.java file in a path of my choosing(so /generated/in/this/specific/folder/R.java

Comment: Create three library modules, each with its own package name. Move the affected code and resources into those three library modules. Add those library modules as dependencies to your main app module.